# Creating new table in Laravel based on user input?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, schema, eloquent

I am trying to create new mysql tables based on user input in the Laravel Framework.

A user submits a form that is processed in a controller, the form data is saved, and then a NEW table is created based on the user's input (to receive data at a later time).

In laravel tables can be created using schema::create()

```
Schema::create('newtablename', function($table){
    $table->increments('id')->unique(); //primary key
    $table->string('columnname');
    etc.
});
```

Essentially I want to do this, except basing the table name and column names on the user's input:

User input is a multidimensional array like this:

```
    $newtableschema = array(
             'tablename' => 'tablename',
             'colnames' => array('One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four');
          );

    Schema::create($newtableschema['tablename'], function($table){
        $table->increments('id')->unique(); //primary key        

        foreach($newtableschema['colnames'] as $col){
            $table->text($col);
        }
        etc.
    });
```

**The error I get is that the variables is not defined. I don't know how to give the user's input to the schema::create method.**

I can't find any method in the documentation for creating tables in this way, or anything similar to this during my last 3 hours of googling. The eloquent syntax confuses me sometimes so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Any ideas? Or is there an alternative pure php/sql to accomplish this?

Many thanks

edit: my apologies, I made a typo earlier in my example code. My issue is that I don't know how to pass the variables I want to schema::create()

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? What is `$newtableschema['array']` ? Is `array` a name of a field or what ?

Comment: Also `$table->text('$colname');` won't work, change it to `$table->text($colname);`.

Comment: my apologies, I made a typo when explaining the code, I have amended the original post to be clearer. The user provides a multidiminsional array, but I can't figure out how to pass it to the create table method in laravel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use `use($newtableschema)` to pass the variable into the `closure`:

```
Schema::create($newtableschema['tablename'], function($table) use($newtableschema) {

    // So now you can access the $newtableschema variable here
    // Rest of your code...
});
```

Comment: Excellent! I can't thank you enough, this solves my problem. I feel silly for even asking now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all... '$colname' is not the same thing as "$colname" and it should be just $colname with no apostrophes.

I am not sure if that will work... but you can try my way.

```
  $table->text('$colname'); $table->text($colname);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put $variable into single quotes PHP think it's normal text so the string is displayed as it was written. You should look at this code:

```
$colname = 'something';

echo '$colname'.'<br />';
echo "$colname".'<br />';
echo "{$colname}".'<br />';
echo $colname.'<br />';
```

Output for this will be:

```
$colname
something
something
something
```

So it's obviously not Eloquent related.

You used:

```
$table->text('$colname');
```

so you tried to create Text file with name exact `$colname` if you want to use it as variable you should simple use in this case:

```
$table->text($colname);
```