# How to create dynamic forms on laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So I want to create a dynamic form but not enough resources on the internet cause I can't find any examples, so I want your suggestion/helps how to do this.

so I have this on my db

[image]

so when I have form `Profile` on view it got like this form base on DB

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ URL::route('postForm') }}">
    <label>First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />

    <label>Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" />

    <label>Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    //same with education form with same post route.
</form>
```

and same with `Education` with different `form_fields` but I don't know too how to handle it on `Controller` to insert data,

```
public function postForm()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $profile = new Profile();
    $profile->first_name = $input['first_name'];
    $profile->last_name = $input['last_name'];
    $profile->password = $input['password'];
    $profile->save();
    //so when the admin create new form, I want to create new table on database
    //and this save() will change into dynamic like
    //$education = new Education();
    //base on form on DB
}
```

so when admin create new forms, so I will code again on the controller. How to do it dynamically?

I already found how to do [create table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979422/creating-new-table-in-laravel-based-on-user-input), just need help on views and on controller

Answer (score 0):

To get Columns names u can use something like this:

```
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing('profiles');

Profile::create(Input::all());
```

Before that in model `Profile`
You need to have `protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'password'];`
Be careful with sensitive data, 
You can

```
$input = Input::only('first_name', 'last_name', 'password');
Profile::create($input);
```